# Conditions in combobox Universal Apps Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, combobox, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm having a problem with combobox. I have two Combobox being conditional to the element selected by another.

```
    <!-- Combo 1 -->

<ComboBox x:Name="Combo1"  Header="Combo1" SelectionChanged="Combo1_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 3"/>
</ComboBox>

<!--Combo 2 -->

<ComboBox x:Name="Combo2"  Header="Combo2" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 4" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 5"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Value 6" x:Name="ComboItemValue6" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is, if the Value2 is selected then have to make visible the Value6 which is collapsed, if I select the Value3 then the Combo2 should become Collapsed, if the Value1 is selected the long term should go to beginning (the Combo2 should reappear, this time without the value 6.) I tried to make it through the SelectionChanged event

```
    private void Combo1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = (sender as ComboBox);
    if ((comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "Value2")
    {
        ComboItemValue6.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    if ((comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString() == "Value3")
    {
        Combo2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
            Combo2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ComboItemValue6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: How did it not work? What's the problem?

Comment: Hello it points the error NullReferenceExcepction

Comment: When does it give that error? When the control is created? When you change the selection of the ComboBox? Also, this exception means that one of the objects that you're using in the handler is null. Which one is it?

Comment: Hello he accuses this exception when it enters the else, specifically the first element else (            Combo2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
)

Comment: How about if you put all of the handler's code in an `if (this.Combo1 != null) { ... }`?

Comment: @yasen worked for the condition of the value 3 which makes the Combo2 collapsed, now for the Value2 condition that displays the comboItemValue6 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with visibility converter.?  Uses this with binding in backend login like in your case bind value2 and value6 with same variable but opposite params so that  when value2 becomes  visible it will collapse value6 and viceversa.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Visibility visibilty = Visibility.Visible;
        string paramType = parameter as string;
        bool isVisible = (bool)value;

        if (paramType == "direct")
        {
            visibilty = (isVisible == false) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (paramType == "invert")
        {
            visibilty = isVisible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return visibilty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hello @aniketpatil forgive my ignorance, is that I could not understand how to apply the visibility converter in the SelectionChanged event above. Can you give me a hand to understand?

Comment: you have to bind visibility of ComboBoxItem to a bool. then change the value of bool according to your requirement.Search for GenericVisibility converter sample if you don't get that tell me I can share the code.